# Consume/absorb a token

Tags: tex-core

How does consume/absorb/remove a token from then token stream in TeX?

I'm using `@ifnextchar` and would like to remove the character it matches.

Comment: With `expl3` there is `\peek_charcode_remove:NTF`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\@ifnextchar` uses `\futurelet` that leaves the token in place. The token can be removed by using `\let`. `\afterassignment` helps to get the control, after the token is assigned and removed. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeifnextchar}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \ltx@LocToksA{\endgroup#2}%
  \ltx@LocToksB{\endgroup#3}%
  \ltx@ifnextchar{#1}{%
    \def\next{\the\ltx@LocToksA}%
    \afterassignment\next
    \let\scratch= %
  }{%
    \the\ltx@LocToksB
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\removeA}{%
  \removeifnextchar{A}{[A is removed]}{[no A]}%
}

\begin{document}

\removeA ABC

\removeA abc

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\ltx@ifnextchar` or `\@ifnextchar` skips spaces. If you want to detect spaces, then use `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace`.

### Removing/reinserting

In general this is not possible, because `\futurelet` does not differentiate between implicit and explicit tokens. For example, the next token can be an opening curly brace `{` or it can be the command `\bgroup` or a command with the meaning of `\bgroup`.
This cannot be distinguished by `\futurelet` or `\let`. The curly brace can be removed by the `\let` trick above. However reinserting is much more difficult. The latter cases `\bgroup` or other command with the same meaning are much easier, they can be catched as macro and reinserted without need to modify the token.

The following example defines a macro `\embrace` that analyzes the following tokens and does different actions depending on the type of the token:

- Letters (catcode 11) are put in parentheses.
- Other characters (catcode 12) are put in square brackets.
- The space is replaced by the underscore.
- Any other token is removed.
- \par terminates the analysis.

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\embrace}{%
  \futurelet\embrace@token\@embrace
}
\newcommand{\embrace@test}[1]{%
  \ifx\embrace@token#1%
    \expandafter\ltx@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\ltx@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\@embrace}{%
  \embrace@test\@sptoken{%
    \textunderscore
    \afterassignment\embrace
    \let\embrace@token= %
  }{%
    \expandafter\IfBeginWith\expandafter*%
    \expandafter{\meaning\embrace@token}{the letter }{%
      \embrace@letter
    }{%
      \expandafter\IfBeginWith\expandafter*%
      \expandafter{\meaning\embrace@token}{the character }{%
        \embrace@character
      }{%
        \ifx\embrace@token\par
        \else
          \@latex@warning{embrace: Token [\meaning\embrace@token] removed}%
          \afterassignment\embrace
        \fi
        \let\embrace@token= %
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\embrace@letter}[1]{%
  (#1)%
  \embrace
}
\newcommand*{\embrace@character}[1]{%
  [#1]%
  \embrace
}

\begin{document}

\embrace ABC 123\par

\embrace a 1{!}#&$x% 

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result of \embrace]

And the removed tokens:

```
LaTeX Warning: embrace: Token [begin-group character {] removed on input line 54.
LaTeX Warning: embrace: Token [end-group character }] removed on input line 54.
LaTeX Warning: embrace: Token [macro parameter character #] removed on input line 54.
LaTeX Warning: embrace: Token [alignment tab character &] removed on input line 54.
LaTeX Warning: embrace: Token [math shift character $] removed on input line 54.
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also include the opposite, insert a single char using the current catcodes(But redefine them locally to get things to work) for completeness if it is not too difficult?

Comment: @AbstractDissonance What you ask for is underspecified. You can insert a control sequence (for instance `\...`) with `\expandafter\next\csname ...\endcsname`, where `\next` is the next thing you want to do.  For character tokens, you can use `\lowercase`: for instance, to get a question mark with catcode 3, you would do `\begingroup\lccode\`$=\`?\lowercase{\endgroup\next$}`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I'm not sure what you mean. Suppose I remove A using Heiko's code and I want to insert it right back(as if I never removed it)... will your code do that? Obviously, I would just use ifnextchar for the same behavior but that isn't the point.  The point about changing cat codes was simply so one could easily insert a special token like `\!inserttoken{\}` would insert a `\` into the stream without throwing an error BUT `\` would have the catcode that was used before the macro call.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance I don't understand what you are trying to acheive: a practical application would be welcome.  Where do you want to insert the token you build?  Also, there is no such thing as a "backslash token (with usual catcodes)", more precisely, catcode 0 is a valid category code for a character before it is read by TeX, but TeX never creates catcode 0 tokens.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Well, How bout you post some code for `\InsertToken` so I can do `\InsertToken{\}mymacro` which would be equivalent to `\mymacro`? Or even `\mym\InsertToken{a}cro`

Comment: @AbstractDissonance It's too late. If TeX forms the token `\mymacro` from the input bytes, you cannot interfere or interrupt using macros. At macro level the tokenization is already done.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ok, for hte second one I can see that tex will try to expand `\mym` before `\InsertToken`. BUT surely for the first case it will expand `\InsertToken{\} first everything should be ok?

Comment: @AbstractDissonance `\mym` is the final token. You can put tokens after it, but that does not change the token `\mym`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek YES, that's I understand that. Ignore that example. What about the first case!!! `\InsertToken{\}mymacro`

Comment: @AbstractDissonance You never get `\mymacro` this way. As Bruno already said, there is no "catcode-0-token". You need the end of the macro name and then you can use `\csname mymacro\endcsname`.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance There are ways of faking that, but none is really correct since TeX has already converted characters to tokens when `\InsertToken` appears.  See the definition of `\`` in `http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/19319/1`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek isn't `\\`` with a catcode of 0 a *catcode-0-token*? Is the TeX parser a look-ahead parser so `\mymacro` will be considered one token? Instead of a stream of tokens? My understanding is that TeX is a statemachine with, IIRC, 3 states. As it parses ascii characters from the tex file it moves around in these states. Can we not interrupt or change the direction and/or state it is in?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch You say it has already converted tokens before `\InsertToken` appears. But I thought TeX processed tokens one at a time and made decisions based on what the previous token or token group was? The way I see it, `\InsertToken{\}mymacro` first calls `\InsertToken{\}` and the macro can do what it wants(insert or remove stuff in the token stream. THEN whatever the "output" of the macro was gets substituted for the call. So we end up with `xxxxmymacro` where xxx is the "output" of the macro call. Now maybe TeX already parsed `xxxx` and won't reparse `xxxxmymacro` as a whole?

Comment: @AbstractDissonance Many nos, see "The TeXbook" or "Chapter 2: Category Codes and Internal States" of [TeX by Topic](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf).

Comment: @AbstractDissonance In principle, it might have been possible to implement Tex in such a way that something similar to what you describe would be possible.  It would be tricky, because what follows `\InsertToken{\}` can be either characters from an input file, or tokens from, e.g., macro expansion.  It would then only make sense to combine the output of the macro with the following stuff if those are characters.