# Applying Macro to xth Symbol of String

Tags: counters, token-lists

I would like to define a command that puts a sequence of symbols above the `x`th symbol of another sequence of symbols.

It seems nicer without a separator, but for higher usability a separator may be necessary. I am not sure.

That means, in the example below the command `\putAbove` should be redefined to produce the output shown behind `becomes`.

The questions seems to be related to e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72827/consume-absorb-a-token), but I am not able to put it into use here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\putAbove}[3]{\backslash putAbove\{#1\}\{#2\}\{#3\}}
\begin{document}
$\putAbove{q_0}{1}{||\phi}$ becomes $\overset{q_0}||\phi$

$\putAbove{q}{1}{||\phi}$ becomes $\overset{q}||\phi$

$\putAbove{q}{3}{|||}$ becomes $||\overset{q}|$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\putAbove}[3]{\xputAbove{#1}{#2}#3}
\newcommand\xputAbove[2]{\ifnum#2=1 \expandafter\xxputAbove\else\expandafter\xxxputAbove\fi{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\xxputAbove[3]{\overset{#1}{#3}}
\newcommand\xxxputAbove[3]{#3\xputAbove{#1}{\numexpr(#2)-1\relax}}

\begin{document}



$\putAbove{q_0}{1}{||\phi}$ becomes $\overset{q_0}||\phi$

$\putAbove{q}{1}{||\phi}$ becomes $\overset{q}||\phi$

$\putAbove{q}{3}{|||}$ becomes $||\overset{q}|$
\end{document}
```

The implementation here is just an iteration based in the observation that

```
\putAbove{q}{1}{abc}
```

is

```
\putAbove{q}{1}a bc
```

which is

```
\overset{q}{a} bc
```

and

```
\putAbove{q}{n}abcde
```

is

```
a\putAbove{q}{n-1}bcde
```

Comment: That is great, thank you! Is it possible that you add a little explanation?

Comment: @HeinrichOdy added some notes

Answer (score 3):

An `expl3` implementation. With `\tl_range_braced:nnn { <tokens> } { x } { y }` you get the items from place `x` to place `y` inclusive. Note that arithmetic is allowed in the second and third argument. Similarly, `\tl_item:nn { <tokens> } { x }` returns the `x`-th item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\putAbove}{mmm}
 {% #1 = symbol to put above, #2 = position, #3 = symbols
  \tl_range_braced:nnn { #3 } { 1 } { #2 - 1 }
  \overset{ #1 } { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { #2 } }
  \tl_range_braced:nnn { #3 } { #2 + 1 } { \tl_count:n { #3 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\putAbove{q_0}{1}{||\phi}$ becomes $\overset{q_0}||\phi$

\medskip

$\putAbove{q}{1}{||\phi}$ becomes $\overset{q}||\phi$

\medskip

$\putAbove{q}{3}{|||}$ becomes $||\overset{q}|$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nicely understandable. But it does not compile for me when I use `\putAbove`. With only the declaration of the command it compiles, though. Any ideas perhaps?

Comment: @HeinrichOdy Most likely you need to update your TeX distribution.